# How to decrypt and decompile luac-file from cocos2d-x framework?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, decompiler, luadec, unluac

I know that the lua version is stored in the 5th byte of the luac file (the header). Here's the first few bytes of a `luac` file I have:

`6D 6D 64 64 74 32`

The 5th byte is `74`. Is [My Luac](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkIxUn6cSIX6sAPOoYdgsLT4Najf) file LuaJIT bytecode?

I am trying to decompile this file and receive this error by using [unluac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac/)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input file does not have the signature of a valid Lua file.
at unluac.parse.BHeader.<init>(BHeader.java:41)
at unluac.Main.file_to_function(Main.java:71)
at unluac.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

and below is error by using [luadec (lua 5.1)](https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec)

```
'=' expected near '?'
```

How can I decompile this file type?

Comment: This file seems to be encrypted.  Probably, it was designed for some host application containing modified Lua which is capable of decrypting a file when loading.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff what should I do now?

Comment: I'm afraid you can do nothing.  You could analyze host executable to learn the encoding algo, but that's not simple...

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff this file come from cocos2d-x framework, any possible idea?